# A cosine function has maximum value of 14 and a minmum value of 4, a period of 7, and a phase shift of 12.

Tags: trigonometry

A cosine function has a maximum value of 14 and a minimum value of 4, a period of 7, and a phase shift of 12. Write an equation representing this cosine function...

Could someone tell me if I'am write and if I'am wrong explain why and a solution my answer $y\,\,\, = \,\,\,14\cos 2\pi {{\left( {x\,\, - \,\,12} \right)} \over 7}\,\,\, + \,\,\,2$

Comment: In your answer, the $14\cos()$ part wiggles between $-14$ and $14$. Adding $2$ we get wiggle between $16$ and $-12$, neither of which is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the max value is $14$ and the min value is $4$, what is the midline value? What is the amplitude? Answering these questions will let you fix your errors--specifically, the $+2$ at the end and the $14$. The rest looks good.

Comment: so  if i'am not mistaken
$y\,\,\, = \,\,\,12\cos 2\pi {{\left( {x\,\, - \,\,12} \right)} \over 7}\,\,\, + \,\,\,2$

Comment: ? does that seem correct now

Comment: Nope. The midline value is the midpoint of the maximum and minimum value--in this case, $9$--so you should have "$+9$" instead of "$+2$." The amplitude is the difference between the maximum value and the midline value--in this case $5$--so you should have replaced your $14$ with $5,$ not $12$.