# The graph of a periodic function is shown below. Determine the amplitude.

Tags: calculus

The graph of a periodic function is shown below. Determine the amplitude.

[image]

I think the answer is A. If i'am wrong could explain why and your reasoning to the correct answers thanks david.

Comment: Hint: what's the amplitude of $f(x)=\sin x$?

Comment: Recall how the amplitude was determined in [this previous question of yours](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/406346/a-cosine-function-has-maximum-value-of-14-and-a-minmum-value-of-4-a-period-of-7).

Answer (score 1):

The amplitude of a periodic function is the distance between the highest value it achieves and the lowest value it achieves, all divided by $2$.  For example, $f(x)=\sin x$ achieves maximum value of $1$, minimum value of $-1$.  The distance between is $2$, hence the amplitude is $1$.

In the problem given, the maximum value is $0$, the minimum value is $-4$.  The distance between is $4$, hence the amplitude is $2$.

Edit: Curious, it seems there are [multiple commonly used definitions of amplitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplitude); one in which @Sami's first answer was right, and the answer is A, and one in which my above answer (and @Sami's revised answer) is right, and the answer is C.

Comment: Sami's answer is equivalent to yours...  right?

Answer (score 1):

$$\text{The amplitude of}\ f= \frac{1}{2}|\max f-\min f|$$